# Unwanted rectangle box around the numbers in the Activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, activity-tab

There is some unwanted rectangle box displaying around the numbers in the **Activity** tab [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451726/arulkumar?tab=questions&sort=votes) and [favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2451726/arulkumar?tab=favorites&sort=votes) pages.

This issue is only in main site not on meta.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: mini-counts]

Comment: It's CSS leaking from the Developer Story.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it.  I kind of like it!

Comment: Ah. Some CSS leaking through. I'll push a fix for this soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. It was a problem with improperly guarded CSS. This has been corrected.

[image: The bug has been corrected.]